# Chrome shows comma instead of decimal point

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, google-chrome

I have a web application (company internal) which shows some form fields with decimal numbers. I've started doing some Javascript with this data. Then I noticed that Chrome shows me the decimal numbers separated with commas instead of decimal point. But Internet Explorer for example shows fine. When I take a look at my C# code I can see, the numbers are truly decimals and they are separated by a decimal point. SO seems to be the code is fine. It have to be something in the HTML rendering (language settings what ever) or with Chrome (I didn't check other browsers than Chrome and IE).

I've never seen this before so where should I search for the mistake?
(I can't show you code. The only thing I can tell you is that the IE Dev console shows a 93.54 while the Chrome Dev console shows a 93,54. Both are values of the same textbox).

Comment: It's almost certainly a locale thing. In some parts of the world, the roles of `.` and `,` are opposite in number representation; sometimes, `.` separates digit groups and `,` separates the integer and fractional parts of the number, and sometimes it's the opposite.

Comment: I would place my bet on @Pointy's reasoning on this

Comment: I know that. But I would like to fix it because I'm not able to parse a 93,54 to a integer while It works with a 93.54. And don't forget: Same system, different Browser. I'm not sure why Chrome would render this in a different local format while IE doesn't.

Comment: I am betting that IE is picking up settings from the underlying OS (obviously Windows) and the other is defaulting to your Google account preferences or using IP-based location to do a best guess.  In Chrome, to change it to English the setting is under Settings->Advanced Settings->Languages

Comment: Oh boy, that's horrible. You're right. When I change it to english it gets rendered with decimal points. What a coding nightmare.

Comment: Most programming languages are locale-sensitive when using the built-in numeric parsing.  Javascript seems to incorporate this using the Number class.  Try something like: `var myNumber = new Number("123,45"); myNumber.toString(); myNumber.toLocaleString();`

Comment: @ChrisShain Isn't toLocaleString() just for date objects? That wouldn't work with a number.

Comment: I was wrong. It works with numbers. You're right!

Comment: There's another problem. toLocaleString takes the system language. But it's possible to change the browser language so it differs from the system. toLocaleString still takes the system language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Asp.NET renders html by Culture Info which come from browser.
By setting thread culture or overriding page method you can render with static culture info.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    this.Culture = "en-US";
    this.UICulture = "en-US";
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```